# Python 3.6.3 Jupyter Notebook: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas' --> Pip Install & Conda both didn't work

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

I am trying to execute a block of code but it errors out:

[image]

I tried doing `pip install geopandas` in my Anaconda prompt but it didn't appear to do anything.

Then I tried doing `conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas` in my Jupyter Notebook itself but I get the following error:

[image]

Would appreciate it if someone can provide **detailed** explanation for what to do from here ... thank you!

Comment: try `!conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas` with the exclamation mark to tell Jupyter that it is not a Python code.

Comment: unfortunately did not work ... same error as before